# With Python, move values from a actual column to the end of a previous column under certain conditions

Tags: pandas, for-loop, while-loop, tolist

In a dataframe, columns with an NaN in the first row should be added to the last column with a number inside. If there are two columns after another with NaN those should both be added to the last column with a number in the first row.

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D | Column E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | NaN | 300 | NaN | NaN |
| R100 | R200 | R300 | R400 | R500 |

The result should look like this:

| Column A | Column C |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 300 |
| R100 | R300 |
| NaN | NaN |
| R200 | R400 |
|  | NaN |
|  | R500 |

and finally:

| Column A | Column C |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 300 |
| R100 | R300 |
| R200 | R400 |
|  | R500 |

Update: So far I got this, but I'm struggeling with column E. It won't be added to the end of column C, where already the numbers of Column D are:

```
import pandas as pd

# Iterate through each column
current_column = 0
while current_column < num_columns:
    if pd.isnull(df.iloc[0, current_column]):
        #print('for loop for', current_column_name)
        # get the name of the current column
        current_column_name = df.columns[current_column]
        # get the name of the previous column
        previous_column = df.columns[current_column - 1]
        # count the values/rows to shift
        count = df[previous_column].count()
        df[current_column_name] = df[current_column_name].shift(count-1)
        # add the values of the current column to the previous column
        #df[previous_column] = df[current_column_name].combine_first(df[previous_column].shift())
        df[previous_column] = df[current_column_name].combine_first(df[previous_column])
        # Delete the current column
        df.drop(df.columns[current_column], axis=1, inplace=True)
        # Update the number of columns after deletion
        num_columns -= 1
    else:
        print('the current column ', current_column_name, 'is not NaN')
    current_column += 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not the best code, but worked for my case with 500+ columns and 100 rows.

```
# Assign column names to transposed DataFrame
df.columns = column_names

# Get the total number of columns
num_columns = len(df.columns)

# Iterate through each column
current_column = 0
while current_column < num_columns:
    # get the name of the current column
    current_column_name = df.columns[current_column]
    # get the name of the previous column
    previous_column = df.columns[current_column - 1]
    # Check if the first entry in the current column is NaN
    if pd.isnull(df.iloc[0, current_column]):
        # Get the value of the first cell in the actual column
        first_cell = df[previous_column].iloc[0]
        # Count the amount of vaules in the actual column
        count = df[current_column_name].count()
        # Shifts the previous column down 1 position
        df[previous_column] = df[previous_column].shift(count-1)
        # add the values of the current column to the previous column
        df[previous_column] = df[current_column_name].combine_first(df[previous_column].shift())
        # add the first value back to the previous column
        df.at[0, previous_column] = first_cell
        # Delete the current column
        df.drop(df.columns[current_column], axis=1, inplace=True)
        # Update the number of columns after deletion
        num_columns -= 1 
    else:
        current_column += 1
´´´
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`lreshape`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.lreshape.html) with a dummy column for Column A (the number of columns must be identical) and `dropna=False`, then [`dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) to remove rows with all `NaN`:

```
out = (pd.lreshape(df.assign(dummy=np.nan),
                   {'Column A': ['Column A', 'Column B', 'dummy'],
                    'Column C': ['Column C', 'Column D', 'Column E']},
                   dropna=False
                   )
         .dropna(how='all').reset_index(drop=True)
      )
```

*NB. if you remove `.dropna(how='all')` you will have the intermediate DataFrame with NaN rows.*

Or with [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), and [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
cols = [['Column A', 'Column B'], ['Column C', 'Column D', 'Column E']]

out = pd.concat({c[0]: df[c].stack().reset_index(drop=True)
                 for c in cols}, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
  Column A Column C
0      100      300
1     R100     R300
2     R200     R400
3      NaN     R500
```

Comment: Hi Mozway, thanks for your reply! I'm still trying to figure out, how I can change the code, to go through all columns step by step. In my case I have about hundreds of columns which I can't check manually to write them into the dictonary. That's why I need to remember the last column with a value in the first row and the columns with a NaN until it reaches the next column with a value inside. Then this is the new column where the following columns with a NaN in the  first row should be added.